# SwiftUI input number and return calculus result

Tags: swiftui

I want to build a small app that calculates my taxes. I need to input a value in a text field, that value should be turned into a float, assigned to a variable and be used for further calculus.

The app is basically a list with intermediate taxes and the final result, with taxes deducted from the input value.

**My issue** is that I can't find a way to turn the STRING input from my TextField() to an Int and use it further down the line.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `String` to `Int` using `Int(someString)`. Even better, you can use directly an `Int` in a `TextField` using:

```
TextField("", value: $someInt) //value instead of text
```